# Display the values using query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to display the values according to the text that which is comes in the drop-down list. one of my friends from this platform helped me to develop that. But that function is only displaying based on two texts. can I add it one more text to generate details?

Here I'm adding the sheet for more clarification. Take a look and you will understand what I need. I want to display which comes under "insurance claim" when we select yes/no.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VsLKHSZsTMeBctnINnsixKISgNkTHDV-dkO4ORsDjgI/edit#gid=595280251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the  `and F contains '"&$C2&"'"` to your current formula on the cell `A5` of the sheet `RESULTS`.

For more details please see the [Query documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Your cell `A5` will become this:

`=query(LIST!A1:G,"Select * where B contains '"&$A2&"' and C contains '"&$B2&"' and F contains '"&$C2&"'")`

If you want to have the values of both sheets in your `RESULTS` sheet, you can add the other sheet to the range of the query:

`=query({LIST!A1:G;LIST2!A1:G},"Select * where Col2 contains '"&$A2&"' and Col3 contains '"&$B2&"' and Col6 contains '"&$C2&"'")`

Comment: @naibas bro.. can we take the result from 'LIST2' in the same 'RESULT'  tab using this formula??

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @naibas bro ... still here ?? can we highlight the entire row according to a name, if yes possible can u show that in that sheet.  kindly highlight the entire row if a column contains 'ferrari' in 'LIST' sheet.

Comment: @naibas bro.. it is not complete yet.. the second formula for taking the results from two sheets is working fine if the template of two sheets are same..i changed the template like my actual workbook, now its showing error